# How to mix x86 and x64 DLLs into the same MSI package?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, profiling, windows-installer

I'm working on a .NET profiler and I need to build 2 DLLs for `64bit` machines (one for `x86` compatible applications and the other for `x64` ones). I want to create a single `MSI` that contains the 2 DLLs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create a single MSI to install the files. However, MSI packages are either 32-bit or 64-bit. A 64-bit MSI package cannot install on a 32-bit machine and a 32-bit package cannot install to 64-bit locations. So, if you are okay with your 64-bit binaries being installed to 32-bit locations (like `C:\Program Files (x86)\`) then you can just add `Condition`s to your `Component`s to get the right bits installed.

For example using the WiX toolset the code could look like:

```
<Component>
  <Condition>NOT VersionNT64</Condition>

  <File Source='path\to\32bit.dll' />
<Compnent>

<Component>
  <Condition>VersionNT64</Condition>

  <File Source='path\to\64bit.dll' />
<Compnent>
```

Comment: Hi Rob, how would this work with x86 + x64 + Arm64 triplet ?

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli, that sounds like a good Question to ask, not a Comment to leave.